# How to cut contour lines at coast line?

Tags: contour, tilemill, gdal-contour

I have successful created a shapefile from an island with contours by downloading the data from http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org, converted it with gdal and imported it in TileMill.

Everything is working very well, except that the contour lines don't stop at the coast. It looks like this coast from OpenTopoMap https://opentopomap.org/#map=17/28.52831/-16.13842

Is there any way to cut or stop the contour lines at the coast?

Comment: Presumably the island boundary is digitised and greater scale than the DEM you derived the contours from. If it's just for visualisation can you just clip the DEM or even the countours?

Comment: Thx for your comment. In a first step I've changed the labeling and now it looks better. But how do I clip the DEM or the contours?